# Duplicate songs when sync with iPad 1

Tags: itunes, ipad, data-synchronization

When I connect my first-gen iPad to my Mac, I have in duplicates in my iTunes. This song have a gray font and have a circle next to their names. Here is a screenshot:[image]

Any idea how to remove this songs? Why do they always show up even after deleting all of my songs off of my iPad?

Answer (score 1):

The songs that you are seeing aren't on your iPad - they are simply still downloading. I believe you can stop them from downloading from the iTunes Store on your iPad or your Mac.

Comment: unfortunately i can not do this :/

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you can use a third-party tool to find and remove the duplicate songs in your iTunes. I once tried with a program called MUSIC CLEANUP. It helped me quickly find and delete all my duplicate songs at once.

Comment: Do you work for the company that produces Music Cleanup or something? You only have two posts, both on the same subject, and both recommending that software.

Answer (score 0):

I find solution here https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3651197?start=15&tstart=0 at leeg330 user answer.